# What to do when a question is answered by a commentor

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

I frequently find myself asking a question,  then having a hint given to me by a com-mentor that is sufficient to figure out the solution to question.
Quite often i even discuss with the individual in the comments section and reach the point where i have understood the question.

frequently after this happens perhaps an hour or two later i get someone who posts an answer to the question that is simply a reiteration of the discussion i had with the com-mentor.

I feel somewhat obligated to accept the the answer. as well... it is in fact correct but my question was already answered and not by them... (i always upvote the comment)

I feel like there should be a button to say question is answered and remove it form the question unanswered que. 
I have thought about deleting the question when this happens but i often feel the question and discussion contributes to the site and would be helpful for others in my situation.

How should i deal with these situations?

Comment: You could ask the commenter to post the comments as an answer to the question. I have seen this done successfully on occasion. Additionally, if enough time passes, and the commenter hasn't replied, you could post an answer yourself giving credit to the comments.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt And, if one posts the answer from someone else's comments, one could label the answer as community wiki.

Comment: I notice that the answers to this question are given in the comments... :)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28263/is-it-acceptable-to-delete-a-question-if-it-has-been-answered-by-a-comment